# How do I fix 'UnboundLocalError: local variable 'dc' referenced before assignment' in my code?

Tags: python, class, variables, user-defined-functions

I'm having trouble finding where exactly dc is being referenced before it's called.  Any help would be appreciated. Code is taken from page 14 of https://cfs.nrcan.gc.ca/pubwarehouse/pdfs/36461.pdf but the code in the manual has some indentation errors. Relevant code (as far as I know):

```
    def DCcalc(self,dc0,mth):
        fl = [-1.6, -1.6, -1.6, 0.9, 3.8, 5.8, 6.4, 5.0, 2.4, 0.4, -1.6, -1.6]
        t = self.t
        if(t < -2.8):
            t = -2.8
        pe = (0.36*(t+2.8) + fl[mth-1] )/2
        if pe <= 0.0:
            pe = 0.0
        if (self.p > 2.8):
            ra = self.p
            rw = 0.83*ra - 1.27 #*Eq. 18*#
            smi = 800.0 * math.exp(-dc0/400.0) #*Eq. 19*#
            dr = dc0 - 400.0*math.log( 1.0+((3.937*rw)/smi) ) #*Eqs. 20 and 21*#
            if (dr > 0.0):
                dc = dr + pe
        elif self.p <= 2.8:
            dc = dc0 + pe
        return dc
```

And my error:

```
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-c2d03971ed28> in <module>
    140         infile.close()
    141         outfile.close()
--> 142 main()

<ipython-input-3-c2d03971ed28> in main()
    129             ffmc = round(fwisystem.FFMCcalc(ffmc0),2)
    130             dmc = round(fwisystem.DMCcalc(dmc0,mth),2)
--> 131             dc = round(fwisystem.DCcalc(dc0,mth),2)
    132             isi = round(fwisystem.ISIcalc(ffmc),2)
    133             bui = round(fwisystem.BUIcalc(dmc,dc),2)

<ipython-input-3-c2d03971ed28> in DCcalc(self, dc0, mth)
     87         elif self.p <= 2.8:
     88             dc = dc0 + pe
---> 89         return dc
     90     def ISIcalc(self,ffmc):
     91         mo = 147.2*(101.0-ffmc) / (59.5+ffmc)

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'dc' referenced before assignment
```

And the main() function at the very end:

```
def main():
    ffmc0 = 85.0
    dmc0 = 6.0
    dc0 = 15.0
    infile = open('c:Documents/data.txt','r')
    outfile = open('fwioutput.txt','w')
    try:
        for line in infile:
            mth,day,temp,rhum,wind,prcp,year=[float(field) for field in 
                                         line.strip().lstrip('[').rstrip(']').split()]
            if rhum>100.0:
                rhum = 100.0
            mth = int(mth)
            fwisystem = FWICLASS(temp,rhum,wind,prcp)
            ffmc = round(fwisystem.FFMCcalc(ffmc0),2)
            dmc = round(fwisystem.DMCcalc(dmc0,mth),2)
            dc = round(fwisystem.DCcalc(dc0,mth),2)
            isi = round(fwisystem.ISIcalc(ffmc),2)
            bui = round(fwisystem.BUIcalc(dmc,dc),2)
            fwi = round(fwisystem.FWIcalc(isi,bui),2)
            ffmc0 = ffmc
            dmc0 = dmc
            dc0 = dc
            outfile.write("%s %s %s %s %s %s\n"%(str(ffmc),str(dmc),str(dc),str(isi),str(bui),str(fwi)))
    finally:
        infile.close()
        outfile.close()
main()
```

Comment: From the PDF you shared, on page 16, the variable dc is declared in the main function. Did you miss this in your code?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I made a few changes in the main() function, but nothing I would consider significant. The dc calls seem to be the same. I edited the question with the main() function for you to check.

Comment: As @Vineet Suryan pointed out, there are cases where `dc` doesn't exist. What is the desired value of `dc` when self.p > 2.8 and dr <= 0.0?

Comment: @Vineet was correct. I added `elif (dr < 0.0): dc = 0` into DCcalc and it's running now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Consider self.p > 2.8 and dr <= 0.0 which makes dc to have never been assigned anything and makes the method return dc which doesnt even exist.

Comment: This was it. I added `elif (dr < 0.0): dc = 0` into DCcalc and it solved my problem. I can now work on all the other problems, ha. Thanks, Vineet!

Answer (score 0):

Consider self.p < 2.8. dc is then never defined before the return.

Comment: Isn't that covered by 'elif self.p <= 2.8: dc = dc0 + pe'?